# Class component vs. function component with intervals

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

Forgive me if this is a redundant question, but I couldn't find an exact answer for my use case anywhere.

I am making a type-writer effect component in React to make a little text adventure purely in React just for fun. I've managed to get it working in the way I like with a class component, but I'd prefer to adapt it to a function component as an opportunity to get better acquainted with function components, but it seems to behave in weird ways with an interval. I've used function components in a lot of different ways before, but for some reason this one stumps me.

Here is a [jsfiddle with the class component.](https://jsfiddle.net/kmcrwf/1s0xwg2e/1/)

```js
class Typewriter extends React.Component {

    state = {
        showCursor: false,
        displayMsgs: []
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.typeSpeed = this.props.typeSpeed ? this.props.typeSpeed : 250
        this.curChar = 0
        this.msgLength = this.props.msg.length
        this.chunks = [{msg: '', flags: {color: "black"}}]
        this.curChunk = 0
        this.inChunk = false

        for(let i = 0; i < this.msgLength; i++) {
            
            if(this.props.msg.charAt(i) === '\\') {
                this.curChunk += 1
                this.inChunk = !this.inChunk
                let flags = { color: "black" }

                if(this.inChunk) {
                    switch(this.props.msg.charAt(i + 1)) {
                        case "R":
                            flags = { color: "red" }
                        break
                        default:
                        break
                    }
                }

                this.chunks.push({msg: '', flags: flags})
                i += 2
            }
            
            this.chunks[this.curChunk].msg += this.props.msg.charAt(i)
        }
        
        this.curChunk = 0
        console.log(this.chunks)
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const displayMsgs = (new Array(this.chunks.length)).fill("")
        this.setState({ displayMsgs: displayMsgs })

        const cursorInterval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({showCursor: !this.state.showCursor})
        }, 250)

        const interval = setInterval(() => {

            const newDisplay = this.state.displayMsgs.map((el, i) => (
                i === this.curChunk ? this.state.displayMsgs[this.curChunk] + this.chunks[this.curChunk].msg.charAt(this.curChar)
                               : el
            ))

            this.setState({displayMsgs: newDisplay})
            this.curChar += 1

            if(this.curChar >= this.chunks[this.curChunk].msg.length) {
                this.curChar = 0
                this.curChunk += 1
                console.log(this.curChunk)
            }

            if(this.curChunk >= this.chunks.length)
                end()

        }, this.typeSpeed)

        const skipTyping = () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
            let newDisplay = []
            for(let i = 0; i < this.state.displayMsgs.length; i++){
                newDisplay.push(this.chunks[i].msg)
            }
            this.setState({ displayMsgs: newDisplay })
            
            end()
        }
        

        const end = () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
            clearInterval(cursorInterval)
            document.removeEventListener("keypress", skipTyping)
            document.removeEventListener("click", skipTyping)
            this.setState({showCursor: false})

            if(this.props.callback)
                this.props.callback()
        }

        document.addEventListener("keypress", skipTyping)
        document.addEventListener("click", skipTyping)
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.displayMsgs.map((msg, i) => 
                    (
                        <span key={i} style={{ color: this.chunks[i].flags.color }}>{msg}</span>
                    )
                )}
                { this.state.showCursor && <span>|</span>}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Typewriter msg="Test message. As you can see it \Rworks\R smoothly." typeSpeed={50} />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

It works smoothly and as I expect it to and I can easily set up my intervals within the
componentDidMount function. This component works with passed callbacks as well, allowing me to chain multiple Typewriter objects in a larger app.

Conversely, I can't seem to make hooks work in this context. I used Dan Abramov's custom hook useInterval, but it behaves choppily and seems way more convoluted that the class component. Here us a [jsfiddle with the functional component.](https://jsfiddle.net/kmcrwf/o4kh5cef/5/) I have only gotten so far as making it work in an ugly way, without the keypresses to skip input, etc.

As you can see, the functional component is really choppy while it's updating; once it is done typing, the cursor blinks at the expected interval/smoothness. For this reason, I suspect there is something funny going on with the rendering that is causing a major performance hit I just can't figure it out. Any insight much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Looks like your issue is a state mutation in the interval callback. You save a reference to the `displayMsgs` state, mutate it, and then save it back into state. React doesn't see a new reference and so bails on the intermediate rerenders and the result is "choppy animation".

```
useInterval(() => {
  if (displayMsgs && curChunk.current < chunks.current.length) {
    let newDisplay = displayMsgs;  // <-- reference to current state

    newDisplay[curChunk.current] += chunks.current[
      curChunk.current
    ].msg.charAt(curChar.current); // <-- Mutation!!!

    console.log('newDisplay', newDisplay);
    setDisplayMsgs(newDisplay);    // <-- save reference back into state
    curChar.current += 1;

    if (curChar.current >= chunks.current[curChunk.current].msg.length) {
      curChar.current = 0;
      curChunk.current += 1;
      console.log(curChunk.current);
    }
  }
}, typeSpeed);
```

## Solution

Shallow copy the state first, then you can update it.

```
useInterval(() => {
  if (displayMsgs && curChunk.current < chunks.current.length) {
    let newDisplay = displayMsgs.slice(); // <-- shallow copy array

    newDisplay[curChunk.current] += chunks.current[
      curChunk.current
    ].msg.charAt(curChar.current);

    console.log('newDisplay', newDisplay);
    setDisplayMsgs(newDisplay);
    curChar.current += 1;

    if (curChar.current >= chunks.current[curChunk.current].msg.length) {
      curChar.current = 0;
      curChunk.current += 1;
      console.log(curChunk.current);
    }
  }
}, typeSpeed);
```

[image: Edit class-component-vs-function-component-with-intervals]